# Can't compile php --with-libmemcached-dir is not recognized?

Tags: php, compiler-errors, libmemcached

I am running into a strange issue when compiling php 7.

I got that error :

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libmemcached-dir

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the truth. --with-libmemcached-dir is an option to compile **the memcached extension**, not php itself.